# Why did biplanes and triplanes go away?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history, biplane

Why did multi-wing aircraft (two or three stacked wings) eventually fade off to single-wing aircraft?

Comment: How does this affects fuel consumption

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate. The other question asks why biplanes used to be more prevalent; this one asks why monoplanes are more prevalent now. (As of right now, this question *also* asks why biplanes used to be more prevalent, but I submitted an edit suggestion to remove that paragraph.)